# How to call specific lambda in mock class?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin

I have next text case with parameters:

```
@Test
fun lostClick() {
        //setup parameters

        val func0 : (Unit) -> Unit = { println("fun0")}
        val func1 : (String) -> Unit = { println("fun1")}
        val func2 : (Int) -> Unit = { println("fun2")}

        whenever(deviceInteractor.reserveBadCaseDevice( //equals `when`
                eq(workerId),
                eq(DeviceCondition.LOST),
                eq(func0),
                eq(func1),
                eq(func2))).then({ func0.invoke(Unit) })

        presenter.lostClick()

        //view reaction
        verify(viewState).showLoad(true)
//        verify(viewState).setButtonGiveEnabled(true) // if func0 called this verify works
//        verify(viewState).setButtonTakeEnabled(false)
//        verify(viewState).setButtonCrashEnabled(false)
//        verify(viewState).setButtonLostEnabled(false)
//        verify(viewState).showLoad(false)
    }
```

But this not works. func0 NOT called. in my presenter this method see this:

```
fun lostClick() {
    reserveBadCaseUser(DeviceCondition.LOST)
}

private fun reserveBadCaseUser(condition: DeviceCondition) {
        showLoad(true)

        //condition == DeviceCondition.LOST
        deviceInteractor.reserveBadCaseDevice(mCurrentWorker?.id!!, condition,
                {
                    clearCurrentDevice()
                    validateButtonView()
                    showLoad(false)
                },
                {
                    showLoad(false)
                    viewState.showErrorToast(it)
                },
                {
                    showLoad(false)
                    viewState.showErrorToast(it)
                })
    }
```

Calling go to showLoad(true) and next call reserveBadCaseDevice not worked. I checked deviceInteractor in test and presenter are one reference, presenter have need values (workerId and DeviceCondition), but method reserveBadCaseDevice not called everything.

How to test my presenter method reserveBadCaseUser when this use class with method with triple lambda function? Or how to mock deviceInteractor correctly that would be called first lamda?

method in deviceInteractor looks like this:

```
fun reserveBadCaseDevice(workerId: Int,
                             condition: DeviceCondition,
                             result: (Unit) -> Unit,
                             errorText: (String) -> Unit,
                             errorId: (Int) -> Unit) {
        val data = ReservedWorkerData(
                DeviceState.TAKE,
                condition, null,
                workerId)

        val call = apiService.postAsyncReserveDevice(data, prefManager.getPrefToken())
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Void>?, response: Response<Void>?) {
                response?.let {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        result.invoke(Unit)
                    } else {
                        errorText(apiErrorUtil.parse(response).message)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>?, t: Throwable?) {
                errorId(apiErrorUtil.parse(t).message)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write test for kotlin lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392445/how-to-write-test-for-kotlin-lambda)

Comment: @nhaarman this answer don't have answers, but have negative reaction. I hope community help in this question

Comment: Please improve your [existing (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46392445/how-to-write-test-for-kotlin-lambda) [questions (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399412/how-to-test-this-class) instead of repeatedly creating new ones.

Comment: eq(func0),
 eq(func1),
 eq(func2))
Isn't this like three times same condition (eq(Unit)). And your function reserveBadCaseUser expects DeviceCondition argument.

Comment: @pokemzok i update post. reserveBadCaseUser in this case 100% have condition == DeviceCondition.LOST - excepted and workerId too

Comment: Ok, so I've got next question. Why are you passing for example eq(func0)? In my opinion you should pass all the params without eq. Every funcion reserveBadCaseDevice argument expects value other than Boolean (I assume eq returns true or false). Also what this line do  "presenter.lostClick()". Is it recurrence or presenter is some instance of other class which you do not post?

Comment: @pokemzok i try it without eq(), with real parameters, where id and condition is a concrete value, but this works similarly. How i know - eq in mockito is a Matcher and if condition return true, then then is worked with them. presenter.lostClick() called this method reserveBadCaseUser() with parameter LOST, i mistake when didn't put that in the question. And yes - some instance. I add this moment in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turned out the solution was pretty simple. Thanks a good community, you really helped!

```
doAnswer{
            println("invoke")
            val args = it.getArguments()

            (args[2] as (Unit) -> Unit).invoke(Unit)
        }.whenever(deviceInteractor).reserveBadCaseDevice(
                eq(workerId),
                eq(DeviceCondition.LOST),
                any(),
                any(),
                any())
```